# Merge vs Synchronize databases

Tags: database, merge

I know, I know... I'm not the first to ask this question but I have gone through numerous posts (on SO as well), but I'm still dissatisfied.  I need to merge tables in two databases that have identical schema/structure.  See example below.  I used a trial of Redgate's SQL Data Compare, but it seems to me that that software only synchronizes Database B to look like A, and often clobbers the data in Database B.  If you know any other software that can do a "true DB merge" (note I DO have Foreign Key relationships set up) effectively, then fine.  Otherwise how can I do this as quickly and reliably in SQL?

Database A:

**PK   Rank**
1     Private  
5     Sergeant

**ID---Name        RankID**
54---Joe           1
60---Frank        1
63---Robert       5

Database B:

**PK  Rank**
2     Private
3     Corporal
4     Sergeant
6     Lieutenant

**ID---Name          RankID**
40---Moe             2
45---Steve           2
67---Max             3
78---Tom             4
80---Peter           6

Ideal Merged Database:

**PK   Rank Description**
1     Private
5     Sergeant
10   Corporal
11   Lieutenant

**ID----Name-----RankID**
54----Joe--------1
60----Frank------1
63----Robert-----5
100---Moe-------1
101---Steve-----1
102---Max-------10
103---Tom-------5
104---Peter-----11

Sorry for the formatting (had a rough time aligning columns).  If it's still not clear what I'm looking for, please let me know